# Method Override get Item of Fragment class was not always called

Tags: android, android-fragments

I get the problem from the time Method Override getItem of Fragment class was not always called anymore. It was only be called in the first time I reach this `CircleFragmentAdapter` class.

This is the class I used and get this problem :

```
public class CircleFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    /**
     * Decide how many view pager in here
     */
    private int mCount = 5;

    private Class<?> Class;

    public CircleFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Class<?> Class) {
        super(fm);

        this.Class = Class;
    }

    /**
     * From beginning this method run,
     * After calling this class again, this method not run anymore.
     */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment mFragment = null;
        if (Class.getSimpleName().equals(
                ActivityDetailSimpleFragment.class.getSimpleName())) {
            switch (position) {
            default:
                mFragment = new ActivityDetailSimpleFragment();
                return mFragment;
            }
        } else if (Class.getSimpleName().equals(
                WelcomeNabuSimpleFragment.class.getSimpleName())) {
            switch (position) {
            default:
                mFragment = new WelcomeNabuSimpleFragment();
                return mFragment;
            }
        } else if (Class.getSimpleName().equals(
                SleepSimpleFragment.class.getSimpleName())) {
            switch (position) {
            default:
                mFragment = new SleepSimpleFragment();
                return mFragment;
            }
        }
        return mFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }
}
```

In my Fragment Class, I called this :

```
circleFragmentAdapter = new CircleFragmentAdapter(getFragmentManager(),
            ActivityDetailSimpleFragment.class);

mViewPager.setAdapter(circleFragmentAdapter);
circlePageIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);
```

If the method getItem can not be called, all fragments I created will not be inflated.

Please tell me how to fix this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed from

`public class CircleFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter`

to

`public class CircleFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

can solved this problem now.